# For $n\ge4,$ prove that $F_n+1$ is not prime, where $F_n$ is $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

**For $n\ge4,$ prove that $F_n+1$ is not prime, where $F_n$ is $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number**

What is the idea of the proof? I tried it by contradiction by 
letting $(1+F_n)$  to be prime $\implies$ $F_n$ is not prime $\implies$ ***WHAT NEXT*?**

Comment: I was hoping to find a covering set of primes. Such as: "all but every third number in this sequence is even, the rest are divisible by one of $3$, $7$, $47$ etc. ..." No cigar for me! The periods of the remainders of Fibonacci numbers modulo a given prime are well understood. But, even so, this may be asking too much??

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:What do you mean by  "covering set of primes"?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen "The periods of the remainders of Fibonacci numbers modulo a given prime are well understood." Is that so? IIRC a thorough study on this topic could possibly lead to a proof of Fermat's last theorem, e.g. Wieferich prime.

Comment: @CaveJohnson what nostalgia your username brings me

Comment: @CaveJohnson I meant: to the extent that we know [the period to be a factor of either $p-1$ or $2(p+1)$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) Those were my clues when searching for a covering set of primes. Do give a link to that relation to FLT, please. That was news to me.

Comment: 8 is also a fibonacci number and not a prime. So you can't prove $F_n$ to be prime. Try something else.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Not quite related to the OP; I just meant that there remains much to be known about the Pisano period :-) [In this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa60/aa6046.pdf), it's proved that a counterexample of the first case of FLT would necessarily be a counterexample to Wall-Sun-Sun conjecture on the Pisano period modolu $p^2$ (not exactly a prime, sorry for the confusion).

Comment: After a bit of testing with Mathematica I'm even less optimistic about finding a covering set of primes. An oddball prime $514229$ occurs as the smallest prime factor of $F_{60}+1$.

Comment: Thanks, @CaveJohnson! I stand corrected

Comment: PKStyles: What's the source of this question?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it appears each is a product of a Lucas number and a Fibonacci number, both gradually increasing.

Comment: That's a great observation @WillJagy! I did notice that my favorite Fibonacci number $1597$ appeared in the list of smallest prime factors.

Comment: This question(answers) show that $F_n\pm 1$ will be prime only in finitely many cases: [Fibonacci(n-1) is always composite for n>6. why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16877/fibonaccin-1-is-always-composite-for-n6-why)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:it is a text problem from Burton's elementary number theory.

Comment: Also related AoPS forum https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1249887p8924937 . It seems to have valid proof, someone please check...

Comment: @Sil I just wrote down these identities and then saw your comment when I was to post them as an answer. lol.

Answer (score 5):

As observed by Will Jagy we can always write $F_n+1$ as a product of a Fibonacci number and a Lucas number.

Let $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$. It is well known that then
$$
F_n=\frac1{\sqrt5}(\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n})
$$
and
$$
L_n=(\phi^n+(-\phi)^{-n}).
$$
Both these sequences of integers satisfy the famous two-step recurrence relation, the difference coming from the initializations $F_0=0, F_1=1$ as opposed to $L_0=2, L_1=1$.

The following factorizations then follow immediately from $F_1=F_2=1$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{2k+1}L_{2k}&=F_{4k+1}+F_1=F_{4k+1}+1,\\
F_{2k-1}L_{2k}&=F_{4k-1}+F_1=F_{4k-1}+1,\\
F_{2k}L_{2k-2}&=F_{4k-2}+F_2=F_{4k-2}+1,\\
F_{2k-1}L_{2k+1}&=F_{4k}+F_2=F_{4k}+1.
\end{aligned}
$$
All the residue classes modulo $4$ were covered, so the claim follows.

---

As an example:
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{2k-1}L_{2k+1}&=\frac1{\sqrt5}(\phi^{2k-1}+\phi^{-(2k-1)})(\phi^{2k+1}-\phi^{-(2k+1)})\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt5}(\phi^{4k}+\phi^2-\phi^{-2}-\phi^{-4k})\\
&=F_{4k}+F_2=F_{4k}+1.
\end{aligned}
$$
It's all about polynomials of $\phi$. You do need to be careful with the parities of the exponents due to that $-\phi$ in the base.

Answer (score 4):

Citing a proof of $F_n \pm 1$ not being a prime by **tastymath75025** from AoPS forum: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1249887p8924937

> **Lemma:** If $n$ is odd, then $F_n^2-1=F_{n-1}F_{n+1}$.
>
> **Lemma 2:** If $n$ is even, then $F_n^2-1=F_{n-2}F_{n+2}$.
>
> **Proof:** For each statement either induct on $n$ or just use Binet's formula.
>
> Now, if $n$ is odd then $(F_n-1)(F_n+1)=F_{n-1}F_{n+1}$. Clearly $F_n-1$ is not prime because $F_n-1 > F_{n-1}$ and $F_n-1 < F_{n+1} < 2(F_n-1)$, so $F_n-1$ cannot divide either factor on the RHS. Similar reasoning finishes for $F_n+1$.
>
> Now, if $n$ is even then $(F_n-1)(F_n+1)=F_{n-2}F_{n+2}$. If $F_n-1$ is prime then clearly it must divide $F_{n+2}$ and not $F_{n-2}$. But it's easy to show $2(F_n-1) < F_{n+2} < 3(F_n-1)$, contradiction, and similarly for $F_n+1$.

As @lhf pointed out in comments, first two lemmas are known as [Cassini and Catalan's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Cassini_and_Catalan%27s_identities). Also worth adding that $F_{n+1} < 2(F_n-1)$ is true for $n\geq 6$, while $F_{n+2} < 3(F_n-1)$ for $n\geq 7$. Rest of the cases can be checked by hand.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Cassini_and_Catalan's_identities

Comment: Nice. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Apparently one and only one way to factor as a Lucas times a Fibonacci number.

```
Sun May 13 13:02:30 PDT 2018

4  1 + F 6 = 3  *  2  Lucas index 2 Fibonacci index  2
5  1 + F 9 = 3  *  3  Lucas index 2 Fibonacci index  3
6  1 + F 14 = 7  *  2  Lucas index 4 Fibonacci index  2
7  1 + F 22 = 11  *  2  Lucas index 5 Fibonacci index  2

8  1 + F 35 = 7  *  5  Lucas index 4 Fibonacci index  4
9  1 + F 56 = 7  *  8  Lucas index 4 Fibonacci index  5
10  1 + F 90 = 18  *  5  Lucas index 6 Fibonacci index  4
11  1 + F 145 = 29  *  5  Lucas index 7 Fibonacci index  4

12  1 + F 234 = 18  *  13  Lucas index 6 Fibonacci index  6
13  1 + F 378 = 18  *  21  Lucas index 6 Fibonacci index  7
14  1 + F 611 = 47  *  13  Lucas index 8 Fibonacci index  6
15  1 + F 988 = 76  *  13  Lucas index 9 Fibonacci index  6

16  1 + F 1598 = 47  *  34  Lucas index 8 Fibonacci index  8
17  1 + F 2585 = 47  *  55  Lucas index 8 Fibonacci index  9
18  1 + F 4182 = 123  *  34  Lucas index 10 Fibonacci index  8
19  1 + F 6766 = 199  *  34  Lucas index 11 Fibonacci index  8

20  1 + F 10947 = 123  *  89  Lucas index 10 Fibonacci index  10
21  1 + F 17712 = 123  *  144  Lucas index 10 Fibonacci index  11
22  1 + F 28658 = 322  *  89  Lucas index 12 Fibonacci index  10
23  1 + F 46369 = 521  *  89  Lucas index 13 Fibonacci index  10

24  1 + F 75026 = 322  *  233  Lucas index 12 Fibonacci index  12
25  1 + F 121394 = 322  *  377  Lucas index 12 Fibonacci index  13
26  1 + F 196419 = 843  *  233  Lucas index 14 Fibonacci index  12
27  1 + F 317812 = 1364  *  233  Lucas index 15 Fibonacci index  12

28  1 + F 514230 = 843  *  610  Lucas index 14 Fibonacci index  14
29  1 + F 832041 = 843  *  987  Lucas index 14 Fibonacci index  15
30  1 + F 1346270 = 2207  *  610  Lucas index 16 Fibonacci index  14
31  1 + F 2178310 = 3571  *  610  Lucas index 17 Fibonacci index  14

32  1 + F 3524579 = 2207  *  1597  Lucas index 16 Fibonacci index  16
33  1 + F 5702888 = 2207  *  2584  Lucas index 16 Fibonacci index  17
34  1 + F 9227466 = 5778  *  1597  Lucas index 18 Fibonacci index  16
35  1 + F 14930353 = 9349  *  1597  Lucas index 19 Fibonacci index  16

36  1 + F 24157818 = 5778  *  4181  Lucas index 18 Fibonacci index  18
37  1 + F 39088170 = 5778  *  6765  Lucas index 18 Fibonacci index  19
38  1 + F 63245987 = 15127  *  4181  Lucas index 20 Fibonacci index  18
39  1 + F 102334156 = 24476  *  4181  Lucas index 21 Fibonacci index  18

40  1 + F 165580142 = 15127  *  10946  Lucas index 20 Fibonacci index  20
41  1 + F 267914297 = 15127  *  17711  Lucas index 20 Fibonacci index  21
42  1 + F 433494438 = 39603  *  10946  Lucas index 22 Fibonacci index  20
43  1 + F 701408734 = 64079  *  10946  Lucas index 23 Fibonacci index  20

44  1 + F 1134903171 = 39603  *  28657  Lucas index 22 Fibonacci index  22
Sun May 13 13:02:30 PDT 2018
```

Comment: This observation was a key to my solution. When you know what to look for it is all plain sailing.

Answer (score 0):

For all $n=3k,3k+1$, $F_n$ will be odd. Which means $F_n+1$ will be even
Still trying for $n=3k+2$ when $F_n$ will be even.

PS: $F_1=1$